# Custom language lexer alias not found by pygments for minted

Tags: minted, code, python

## Problem

I've made a custom lexer for a pseudocode language in Python (3.11). The file is saved in the same directory as my TeX project. I am using `pdflatex` to compile my project, and it has the `--enable-write18` flag (so `shell-escape` is enabled) added the compilation command through TeXMaker.

Yet, every time I compile my document, it brings up an error for a brief moment which states:

```
Error: no lexer for alias 'pseudocodefile.py:MyCustomLexer -x' found
```

As a result of this, my pseudocode does not get printed either. I really don't know if this is a LaTeX issue, or a python one. If this is too off-topic, I am happy to take this to StackOverflow.

## MWE

### Lexer code (Python 3.11)

```py
from pygments.lexer import RegexLexer, words
from pygments.token import *

class MyCustomLexer(RegexLexer):
    name = 'Pseudocode'
    aliases = ['mycustomthingo']
    filenames = ['*.pseudocode']

    tokens = {
        'root': [
            (words(('and', 'not', 'or', 'xor', 'Return', 'True', 'False'), suffix=r'\b'), Keyword),  # Logic and return
            (words(('If', 'Then', 'Else'), suffix=r'\b'), Keyword),  # Control flow
            (words(('For', 'From', 'To', 'Step', 'EndFor', 'While', 'EndWhile', 'Define', 'Print'), suffix=r'\b'), Keyword),  # Loops, function definitions, and custom functions
            (r'\b(\d+(\.\d+)?)\b', Number),  # Numeric data types
            (r"('[^']*'|\"[^\"]*\")", String),  # Strings
            (r'\b[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\b', Name),  # Identifiers
        ]
    }


MyLexer = MyCustomLexer
```

### TeX file

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}

\title{Minted test}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
% Indentation removed from environment
\begin{minted}{pseudocodefile.py:MyCustomLexer -x}
Define f(x):
    Return x * x
\end{minted}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of **12/10/2023**, the [minted latex package documentation](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) does not elaborate on how to specify a custom lexer from a user-defined python script so I am not sure it is an intended feature. However, after looking at [minted codebase](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) and the [documentation for Pygments](https://pygments.org/docs/), I found a quick hack that you can apply to your code with minted **version 2.8** so that you can use a custom lexer. I also want to say that it correct and still is imperative for you to use `shell-escape`  as this is necessary for minted to work; however it is not the cause of the error: `Error: no lexer for alias 'pseudocodefile.py:MyCustomLexer -x' found`

### The solution

**Use quotations** around the argument that specifies the location of your custom lexer with the command line option -x. **Make sure** these quotations do not have any padding of space around its content and the outer curly brackets. Also, the type of quotation that needs to be used is dependent on whether you are compiling with windows or not.

**Corrected segment compiling on Windows**

```latex
\begin{minted}{"pseudocodefile.py:MyCustomLexer -x"}
Define f(x):
    Return x * x
\end{minted}
```

**Corrected segment compiling on Linux/Macos**

```latex
\begin{minted}{'pseudocodefile.py:MyCustomLexer -x'}
Define f(x):
    Return x * x
\end{minted}
```

If you want a platform independent solution, consider using the `\ifwindows` macro. However, the `\ifwindows` logic must be outside of curly brackets that indicate the argument. This is because the argument is detokenized behind the scenes, meaning that what is thought as evaluating latex commands are actually verbatim text.

### Why this works

The quotations that are used here are there to actually escape the quotations the minted environment wraps around that argument behind the scenes. If these quotations are not escaped, minted will call the the command (assuming a windows os but similar to others):

`pygmentize -l "pseudocodefile.py:MyCustomLexer -x" ...`

to analyze your code segment. But the `"pseudocodefile.py:MyCustomLexer -x"` is considered one argument instead of two distinct ones `pseudocodefile.py:MyCustomLexer` and `-x`, which causes the error you have. Wrapping the argument with additional quotations effectively cancels out the quotations minted creates behind the scenes, since the quotations now syntactically represent the prepending an empty character to `pseudocodefile.py:MyCustomLexer` and appending an empty character to `-x`:
`""pseudocodefile.py:MyCustomLexer -x""` is equivalent to `pseudocodefile.py:MyCustomLexer -x`

### If it still does not work

Check that `pseudocodefile.py` is in the current working directory where you are calling latex commands or specify a correct absolute/relative path to your lexer python script.